# S is a finite set show that $|P(S)|$ is $2^{|S|}$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If $S$ is a finite set, show that $|P(S)| = 2^{|S|}$.

So I know that $|P(S)|$ means the number of elements in the power set of $S$, but I don't understand the relation between the power set and $2^{|S|}$. 
I tried doing:

Suppose $|S|=n$, then $|P(S)|$ = the union of each subset of $S$. Then $|P(S)|$ is the set $\{x_1, x_2, x_3, .... x_n\}$. But I'm not even sure if I'm thinking about this right. 
Any help would be awesome!

Comment: $P(S)$ is the set of all subsets of $S$. $|P(S)|$ is the number of subsets of $S$, so it is not a set.

Comment: @Spenser: In ZF, everything is a set.

Comment: @Spenser , I still don't understand it though. How can I show that |P(S)| = $2^{|S|}$ ? How should I define |P(S)|?

Comment: say $S=[1,n]$ for convenience.  define $f:\mathcal{P}(S)\to\{0,1\}^{|S|}$ by $f_i(A)=0,1$ depending on whether or not $i\in A$

Comment: For each subset $ A \subseteq S $, define a function $ f_{A}: S \to \{ 0,1 \} $ by
$$
{f_{A}}(x) \stackrel{\text{df}}{=}
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if $ x \in A $}; \\
0, & \text{if $ x \notin A $}.
\end{cases}
$$
Then there is a bijection between $ \mathcal{P}(S) $ and the set $ \{ f_{A} \mid A \subseteq S \} $ of functions from $ S $ to $ \{ 0,1 \} $. The cardinality of the latter set is easily seen to be $ 2^{|S|} $.

Answer (score 1):

Let $|A| = n$

To construct $\mathscr{P}(A)$ it will consist of each possible subset.  By the multiplication principle, the number of different subsets can be counted by the following steps:

Step 1: is the first element in the subset? (Yes or No: 2 possibilities)

Step 2: is the second element in the subset? (Yes or No: 2 possibilities)

$\dots$

Step k: is the kth element in the subset? (Yes or No: 2 possibilities)

$\dots$

Step n: is the final (nth) element in the subset? (Yes or No: 2 possibilities)

By the multiplication principle, each specific way of making choices at each step gives rise to a different subset, and so the total number of subsets is the same as the multiplication of each choice.  Hence, $2\cdot2\dots\cdot2 = 2^n$

So, $|\mathscr{P}(A)| = 2^{|A|}$

Comment: so is this similar to probability?